# How would I write my own FirstOrDefaultAsync() method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I am starting to get my head around the async/await programming model and trying to understand the patterns and how to use them.

Given I I have a Method that returns `Task<List<string>> GetListAsync()`

How can I write my own FirstOrDefault() method like this

```
Task<string> result = GetListAsync().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

this doesn't feel right:

```
 var resultList = await GetListAsync();
 var firstElementTask = Task.FromResult(resultList.FirstOrDefault());
```

What would be I valid approach which doesn't break the async/await programming model?

Comment: There isn't anything. Async wasn't designed to support lists, a hole that Microsoft is well aware of and plans to address in the next version of C# after 2015.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Do you have any sources for that?

Comment: Here's the article I wrote on the topic with links to my sources. http://www.infoq.com/news/2015/01/CSharp-7-Intro

Comment: Are you sure, you need so strange construction? After `var list = await GetListAsync()` you already have the fully-constructed `List`.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I would phrase that as "thinking about addressing that" as it's very early in the discussion phase.

Answer (score 4):

You should realize that basing `FirsOrDefaultAsync` on top of `GetListAsync` means that when the asynchronous operation completes the entire list would be materialized. (i.e the `Task<List<string>>` completed and resulted in `List<string>`)

So there's no real use in even having `FirsOrDefaultAsync`. It would always be equivalent to:

```
var list = await GetListAsync();
var result = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

The only way to have a true asynchronous `FirsOrDefaultAsync` is to have support from the provider to only query the first item asynchronously and not the entire list.

There's an inherent conflict between LINQ and `async-await` as they both rely on the compiler transforming your code into state machines. That's why Reactive Extension exists (which may be worth checking out). Another nice solution could be found in the MongoDB C# driver where they reinvented `IEnumerable` as `IAsyncCursor`.

If that's okay and all you want is a helper method then this is it:

```
public async Task<string> FirstOrDefaultAsync()
{
    var list = await GetListAsync();
    return list.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When your method returns `Task<List<string>>` then it doesn't makes much sense to create `FirstOrDefaultAsync`. You certainly can, but it isn't much helpful.

Because you can't get the `List<string>` till the Task completes. Once the task completes you'll be left with `List<string>` which is in memory collection. It have all the elements you need. At this point you can just call `yourList.FirstOrDefault()`.

On the other hand, it makes sense to create `FirstOrDefaultAsync` when you have `List<Task<string>>` or `IEnumerable<Task<string>>`.

```
public async Task<T> FirstOrDefaultAsync<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var first = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    return await first;
}
```

As @i3arnon noted in comments this method returns the result of task whichever happens to complete first. Not the first one in the list.

Comment: "first" in this case is just the first task that happened to complete in time, regardless of order and non-consistent.

Comment: @i3arnon You're exactly right. If you need the first one in order, you don't even need a list of tasks. You could just use `Task<T>` alone.

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a `Task<List<x>>`, so when the task completes, you get a list. Period. Second fact: you are using await to get the list. This makes the calling method already async. You don't need to manually wrap anything in a task:

```
var resultList = await GetListAsync()
return resultList.FirstOrDefault();
```

and that should be it.

However, this of course STILL fetches the whole list. But this is a flaw in the design of the "GetList" method. Since it returns a list, there's not much anything can be done. Unless the List has lazy implementation, it will always return whole list.

If you have control on that piece code, you could try to rewrite the GetListAsync to return IEnumerable/IQueryable and make sure they are processed lazily, but that's another topic.

Comment: No, you can't return a lazy `IEnumerable` from an `async` method.

Comment: @i3arnon: and what/who/when would check if my returned IEnumerable was lazy or not? What prevents me from returning from the Task a handcrafted IEnumerable implementation that internally uses proper waiting/threading/scheduling/etc before returning the next element? When thinking about possible Laziness, focus on a blocking IEnumerable.

Comment: If the `IEnumerable` is blocking then it's not asynchronous.

Comment: @i3arnon: Wow. What a suprise. How in your opinion IEnumerable  having MoveNext() and CurrentElement could ever be implemented asynchronously? Is it `Task<T> CurrentElement` ? No. It's `T CurrentElement` for god's sake. Either use `IEnumerable<Task<T>>` or don't use IEnum. IEnumerable cannot be async by-def. IList cannot be async by-def. ICollection, IDictionary, etc, neither. If you want to have "async ienumerable", then ienumerable is not for you. Use Reactive and subjects/observers or similar tools.

Comment: So you agree..  you can't return a lazy `IEnumerable` from an `async` method.

Comment: @i3arnon: And all of that does not prevent "async GetFoo" from returning lazy IEnumerable, and it does not prevent anyonw from writing a lazy enumerable, and the synchronicity of the IEnuerable does not prevent anyone from writing an `async FirstOrDefault` that will properly work on that.

Comment: @i3arnon: Do you really not understand? "Lazy Ienumerable" is NOT the same thing as "async IEnumerable". Lazy IE is possible and is returnable from async method. Async IE is not possible at all.

Comment: And BTW, the synchronicity of `IEnumerable` completely prevents you from writing an async `FirstOrDefault` that will properly work since if the iteration is synchronous, there's nothing `async` in the operation. It would be *at best* the same as `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: @i3arnon: Analyze this: `public static Task<int> First(this IEnumerable<int> self) { return new Task<int>(() => System.Linq.Enumerable.First(self)); }` and try to argue that it does not create an asynchronous "First" from a synchronous IEnumerable. After you understand this example, please tell me if I really need to write the rest of the code.

Comment: Well... first, you never start the task, so it would never complete. You probably meant to use `Task.Run`. Second, `First` isn't an `async` method, it just returns a `Task`. Third, it isn't naturally asynchronous. it just offloads the synchronous operation to a different thread. Basically that method is useless as it's simply this "fake" asynchronous line of code: `Task.Run(() => list.FirstOrDefault())`. No one should write that line and definitely not create an extension method just for that.

Comment: @i3arnon: First, I wrote it on the fly so typos and small irrelevant bugs are granted and does not cancel the point. Second, that First is not "async" per C# keyword, but it is asynchronous in usage. Third, yes, it is not "internally asynchronous" because the IEn. cannot be. It is not useless, because it allows you to wait for a result from blocking IEn without blocking your own thread.

Comment: It's not asynchronous at all and It's useless because it doesn't add any value over the simple line of `Task.Run` with LINQ's `FirstOrDefault`. And even this line is useless almost everywhere outside the UI thread. `LINQ` and `async` simply don't work together. `IEnumerable` is synchronous and can't be `async`. "Lazy" `IEnumerable` is created using `yield` which can't be used in an `async` method. In conclusion: **Don't mix fluent LINQ and `async`.**

Comment: and read this: [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx)

Comment: @i3arnon: I will repeat it last time: Lazy IEnumerable can be returned from an `async` method. `async Task<IEnumerable<int>> Foo() { return really(); } IEnumerable<int> really() { yield return 5; yield return 6; yield return 7; yield return 8; }` it is lazy, and is returned from async method. And please, just dont tell me that 'return really()' is synchronous. What I started to argue with was your comment `No, you can't return a lazy IEnumerable from an async method`. I hope this proves you something. Please,start reading what people write,not what you think they wrote. Your rep is irrelevant.

Comment: I know that article. Funny thing, it tells you what should be done, not what can be done. The whole question in its title exists because it is possible to create async wrappers for sync things! Please note I dont argue we should.

Comment: Yes! You do! The OP asked how to write `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and you gave an answer that could only work synchronously because, just as you don't want to hear, `return really()` **is** synchronous. You can't truly combine naturally `async` with `IEnumerable` no matter how you try to justify it. You should simply avoid doing that. Of course it's possible to do "sync over async", it's just useless and bad.

Comment: @i3arnon: Please, take some rest and reconsider it with fresh mind. I never said we should use "sync over async". I only said we can. I also never said we can have truly async IEnumerable or awaitable IEnumerable, that's impossible, and I'm stressing it from the start. What I said is that if someone tried hard, then returning lazy IEnumerable or lazy List is possible, You said I can't and all the time I'm trying to show you that very possible. I don't encourage, I don't advertise, I just say it is possible.

Comment: @i3arnon: In the last example, `really()` is synchronous for simplicity of the example. It could do some asynchronous work and then construct/configure lazy IEnumerable and return it. Object construction hardly can be made truly asynchronous. But it was not the point. The point is that it **returns** a **lazy IEnumerable**. The IEn is created by `really` method and then returned. This IEn is a generator and obviously this generator is lazy. This means it is possible to return **lazy IEn** (not async-IEn!!) from async method, and just did so in the example. You said I can't. That's only that.

Comment: Well, yes. You **can** do "sync over async" but then it's not async, and so irrelevant to the OP's question. Saying "you could" do something in an SO answer without saying "but you shouldn't" deserves a comment when that thing is bad advice. You didn't stress from the start that `IEnumerable` and async don't go together ([that's what I did](http://bit.ly/185BEgX)). You can't generate a lazy `IEnumerable` in an async way, passing a lazy `IEnumerable` from a different method and pretending it's async is worse than simply making everything sync.

Comment: **You just shouldn't mix unmaterialized collections with async**. You either [break the unmaterialized part](http://bit.ly/1DGjbTK) (so return `Task<List<T>>` instead) or you [break the async part](http://bit.ly/185BEgX) (so return `IEnumerable<T>` instead). Either don't suggest that, or explain why it's wrong ([as I did](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28602147/885318)). As long as you don't, this answer hurts the OP and everyone else that finds it in the future.